# Chrome и MacOS: определение локации и обработка system preferences

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, macos

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой - использую метод для определения текущего местоположения устройства:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {timeout: 10000})
```

Если  в браузере дать доступ на определение(левая pop-up  на скрине), то координаты не определятся и через 10 секунд ***errorCallback*** обработает ***timeout*** (а если ***timeout*** не задать, то вообще ничего не произойдет, определение как бы зависнет в "воздухе"). Просле этого нужно дополнительно кликнуть на иконку локации в строке браузера(правая pop-up на скрине) и открыть системные настройки со всеми доступами. Но существует ли способ, как можно самому (на этапе загрузки страници, напр.) определить, что "*location is turned off in Mac system preferences*", что бы потом автоматически вызвать этот pop-up (ну или какую-нибуть кастомную модалку)? ***errorCallback***, к сожалению, не обрабатывает эту ошибку.

[image: location]